# Solving system of equations for grid world AI

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzKc4.png

The above system of equations represents represent the constraints and goals of an agent navigating a grid world. Where position is a function of time T. My question being. Is it possible to solve for this series of equations. I also am curious if people have tried similar things with grid worlds.

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to inline the equations in the question. Many cannot view images and this would be a hassle for them.Also please include any thoughts or things you have tried out in solving the problem at hand. cheers ,Hope you have a nice time in MSE.

Comment: The square roots within the arcsins are all 1, then taking the sin of each can simplify it.

Comment: Are you trying to solve for $T_{11}, T_{12}, T_{21}, T_{22}, T_{31}, T_{32}$?  Why are $X$ and $Y$ in two equations then equal to zero? Are there actually ten equations for the six (or eight if we include $X$ and $Y$) variables, so the system is over-determined?